# "=" sign in href link showing =3D on client side

Tags: html-email

When my HTML email is sent to a customer all of the "=" signs have "3D" added to them. Most of the email is fine with this change but there is a crucial link that includes a "=" but when "3D" is added it changes the variable and it does not work. How do I make sure links in the email that include "=" work?

We have a form that a user submits. Essentially an email is triggered from their submission and a unique url is generated (example https://www.sampledomain.com/page.html?v=UserSpecific_Code123). I have the html email setup but when it is sent the "=" in the url is changed to "=30" which messes up the destination. How do I make sure the "=" stays and goes to the right place?

```
href=3D"https://d1nomjv13ngyfe.cloudfront.net=
/VanquishPromo/vanquish_player.html?v=3DVideo_Sample_VanquishPromo429099537=
3816553113
```

The href should just be https://d1nomjv13ngyfe.cloudfront.net/VanquishPromo/vanquish_player.html?v=3DVideo_Sample_VanquishPromo4290995373816553113

Comment: It's an email encoding system called "quoted-printable", which allows non-ASCII characters to be represented as ASCII for email transportation.

In quoted-printable, any non-standard email octets are represented as an = sign followed by two hex digits representing the octet's value. Of course, to represent a plain = in email, it needs to be represented using quoted-printable encoding too: 3D are the hex digits corresponding to ='s ASCII value (61).

But how to fix it, im not sure :-(

Comment: Is it by any change an outlook the customer is opening on? What system triggers the email?